# Is the set of positive function set in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a bounded and open domain with smooth boundary. Define the set
$$
A:=\{u\in H^{-1}(\Omega)~|~u(x)\geq0,~a.e.~x\in\Omega\}.
$$
Is the set $A$ closed?

Comment: Well, technically $u \in A$ are such that $u: H^1_0(\Omega) \to \mathbb R$ so that your condition $u(x) \ge 0$ doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The dual space $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ can be seen as
$$
H^{-1}(\Omega)\cong \left\{u:\Omega\to\mathbb R~|~\exists L>0~s.t.~\int_\Omega uvdx\leq L\|v\|,~~\forall v\in H_0^1{\Omega}\right\}.
$$

Comment: That's why I used the word "technically"

Comment: Thanks for your opinion on this issue. I'm currently working on a mapping constrained on $A$, and the associated results all require $A$ to be closed. Therefore I want to know whether this set is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you identify $H^{-1}$ to $H^1_0$ (you can always do that by Riesz representation theorem), you can consider $f \in \text{cl }A$ and $(f_n)_n \subset A$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $H^1_0$. In particular $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ and the exists a subsequence (still denoted $f_n$) such that $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere. This implies that $f \ge 0$ a.e.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a different opinion(maybe I don't fully understand your answer). By Riesz representation theorem, we known that $H_0^1(\Omega)\cong H^{-1}(\Omega)$, actually, under the isomorphism $-\Delta: H_0^1(\Omega)\to H^{-1}(\Omega)$. I think "$f_n\to f$ in $H_0^1(\Omega)$" in your answer is based on the pair
$$
\langle f,u\rangle=\int_\Omega \nabla f\nabla udx.
$$
In this case, we get $H_0^1(\Omega)=H^{-1}(\Omega)$. Then
$$
A=\{u\in H_0^1(\Omega)~|~u\geq0,~a.e.~x\in\Omega\}.
$$
In this case, $A$ is obviously  closed.

Comment: However, our work is on the following pair
$$
\langle f,u\rangle=\int_\Omega fudx.
$$
Then $f_n\to f$ in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ just implies $u_n\to u$ in $H_0^1(\Omega)$, where $u_n$ and $u$ satisfy $-\Delta u_n=f_n$ and $-\Delta u=f$, respectively.

Comment: If $u_n \to u$ in $H^1_0$ then it converges in particular in $L^2$ by Poincaré inequality.

Comment: I known this. But how to come to $f\geq0$ a.e.. Now we don't have $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$.